# Can I extract significane values for Logistic Regression coefficients in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, logistic-regression, significance

Is there a way to get the significance level of each coefficient we receive after we fit a logistic regression model on training data?

I was trying to find out a way and could not figure out myself.

I think I may get the significance level of each feature if I run chi sq test but first of all not sure if I can run the test on all features together and secondly I have numeric data value so if it will give me right result or not that remains a question as well.

Right now I am running the modeling part using statsmodel and scikit learn but certainly, want to know, how can I get these results from PySpark ML or MLLib itself

If anyone can shed some light, it will be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use only mllib, I think that when you train a model you can use toPMML method to export your model un PMML format (xml file), then you can parse the xml file to get features weights, here an example

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/mllib-pmml-model-export.html

Hope that will help

Comment: Thanks for this response. For the moment, I used a hybrid approach where I ELT'd the input data using pyspark and then did the modeling by switching over to statsmodels. That has worked for me. Surely I lost on the Spark's benefits but it just helped for my purpose.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. He asked for feature significance, not weights.